# Capturing audio out for use in a web page

Tags: audio, scripting, web, out

I am wondering if it is possible, using JavaScript, php, or any other method to capture general 'audio out' or line out, and send it to be used in a web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. With custom (non-web) code, this often requires special custom drivers to be written (depending on the OS).